# Javascript Async function returns promise and not actual value

Tags: javascript

I currently have an async function but it only returns `Promise { <pending> }` and not the actual return value.

My function is as follows:

```
async function testFunction() {
  try {
    var resp = await deepai.callStandardApi("sentiment-analysis", {
      text: "This is a test.",
  });
  return resp.output;
}
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

console.log(testFunction())
```

Does anyone know how I can return the actual content and not `Promise { <pending> }` ?

Would appreciate any help at all and thank you in advanced for your time.

Comment: The return value of an async function is always a promise. If you want the actual value then either await it in another async function or else register a callback with the then method.

Comment: For example, `testFunction().then(console.log)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the real value, you should do await in another async function.

Updated Code:

```
async function testFunction() {
  try {
    var resp = await deepai.callStandardApi("sentiment-analysis", {
      text: "This is a test.",
  });
  return resp.output;
}
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

(async function() {
   console.log(await testFunction());
})();
```